# Haskell: Call a function for each list from tuple

Tags: haskell, tuples

I'm trying to solve one of a HackerRank problem, [Cats and a Mouse](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cats-and-a-mouse/problem), using Haskell.

I've implemented the logic to solve the problem, though facing some trouble getting the input and parsing to the required shape.

Code:

```
solve :: [Int] -> String
solve input
    | catA == catB = "Mouse C"
    | catA > catB  = "Cat B"
    | otherwise    = "Cat A"
    where catA = abs $ input !! 0 - input !! 2
          catB = abs $ input !! 1 - input !! 2

main = interact $ unlines . map solve . splitAt 3 . map read . tail . words
```

I know that splitAt function returns a tuple. So I need help in parsing the tuple here.

I need to call solve function for each list present in the tuple and append the result to output.

Can someone please help me solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want `splitAt 3`, you want [`Data.List.Split.chunksOf 3`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.4/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf). If you don't have Data.List.Split available on hackerrank, you'll need to reimplement chunksOf one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do it is to simply replace your `map solve` with a simple anonymous function:

```
main = interact $ unlines . (\(a, b) -> [solve a, solve b]) . splitAt 3 . map read . tail . words
```

If you dislike anonymous functions, you could always extract it under some name and define it, either as a top level function, or in a `where` clause.

Comment: The output from `splitAt 3` will looks like, `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],...]`
But in this case it was mentioned just a and b which I didn't understood completely. Could you please explain?

Comment: Oh, I assumed you were referring to [this function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt) which, as you can see, returns a pair of lists. Especially as you said in your question that it returns a tuple. If it does return a list of lists then your original `map solve` should compile and work fine, and there would be no need for this question.

Comment: with `map solve`, I'm getting the error. https://pastebin.com/pMV09E19 check this for complete error trace

Comment: That matches what I expected - it shows that the output of `splitAt 3` is indeed a pair of lists, so my answer above should work. Please let me know if you are getting a different error, I confess I haven't had a chance to test it.

Comment: @RobinZigmond The point is that `splitAt` isn't what they want, so anything you can do with the result of that is no good.

Comment: @amalloy OK, that's not at all obvious to me, as the question just says they want "help in parsing the tuple here". I don't know if it's the right tool to solve the wider problem - I didn't click the link, because SO questions should be self contained, and I didn't need to in order to answer the question that was asked. If the OP really wanted the answer to a different question they should have asked that one.

Comment: Right, I didn't follow the link either - I guessed it from the first comment on your answer, since "a list of test cases" is a common input format for things like hackerrank and Baranidharan S seemed to think the result would be in that format but in fact splitAt doesn't do that.